# Improve Code Reuse (Python-style decorator for c#?)

Tags: c#, python, dry

I'm moving from python to c#, and one of the things I miss is python-style decorators. If I had repeated code at the top of a load of functions (validation checking etc), I could create a decorator to do it.

I've seen that there are c# decorators of a sort, but they look like they work more on the class level. Although I am a bit confused by them.

Regardless - how would you go about improving code re-use/DRY in this function? All the stuff in the function is common, except the two places marked. Its callback driven Tcp requests to a server, with a block to stop multiple concurrent requests (check for Idle state).

```cs
    public void MyFunction(string apples, Action<TcpRequest> onSuccess=null, Action<TcpRequest> onError=null)
    {
        // Throw exception if already busy with an operation
        if (!state.Has(State.Idle)) { throw new OperationInProgress(); }

        // Define callback action
        Action<TcpRequest> callback = delegate (TcpRequest request)
        {
            // Add idle state back in
            state.Add(State.Idle);

            // Check if the request succeeded
            if (request.OK)
            {
                /**
                 * Unique code here
                 */
            }
            // Request failed. Call the onError callback if provided
            else { onError?.Invoke(request); }
        };

        // Remove idle state
        state.Remove(State.Idle);

        /**
         * Unique code here, that will later trigger the callback
         */
    }
```

EDIT: I wasn't really thinking of this as a code review task, but now I can see it is. Here is the whole class, showing how the states/vars interact. The Server class handles interactions between us (the client) and a webserver to handle game login, and create/join match.

I'm not fixed on any particular structure, but at some point I want to connect UI buttons to simple functions like `Server.Login()` and `Server.JoinMatch()`, without needing to spawn messy classes.

```
public class Server
{
    #region Fields
    public string playerName { get; private set; }
    public string playerID { get; private set; }
    public string playerToken { get; private set; }
    public string currentMatchID { get; private set; }
    private Patterns.State<ServerState> state = new Patterns.State<ServerState>();
    #endregion

    public Server()
    {
        state.Add(ServerState.Idle);
    }

    public void Login(string playerName, Action<TcpRequest> onSuccess = null, Action<TcpRequest> onError = null)
    {
        // Throw exception already busy with an operation
        if (!state.Has(ServerState.Idle)) { throw new OperationInProgress(); }

        // Define login callback action
        Action<TcpRequest> loginCallback = delegate (TcpRequest request)
        {
            // Add idle state back in
            state.Add(ServerState.Idle);

            // Check if the request succeeded
            if (request.OK)
            {
                // Store player data in class
                playerName = (string)request.requestJson["player_name"];
                playerID = (string)request.responseJson["player_id"];
                playerToken = (string)request.responseJson["player_token"];

                // Add the logged in state
                state.Add(ServerState.LoggedIn);

                // Call the onSuccess callback if provided
                onSuccess?.Invoke(request);
            }
            // Login failed, call the onError callback if provided
            else { onError?.Invoke(request); }
        };

        // Remove idle state
        state.Remove(ServerState.Idle);

        // Perform request
        Request("login", callback: loginCallback, requestJson: new Dictionary<string, object> { { "player_name", playerName }, { "client_version", "test1" } });
    }

    public void CreateMatch(string matchName, Action<TcpRequest> onSuccess = null, Action<TcpRequest> onError = null)
    {
        // Throw exception already busy with an operation
        if (!state.Has(ServerState.Idle)) { throw new OperationInProgress(); }

        // Define callback action
        Action<TcpRequest> callback = delegate (TcpRequest request)
        {
            // Add idle state back in
            state.Add(ServerState.Idle);

            // Check if the request succeeded
            if (request.OK)
            {
                // Add the inLobby state
                state.Add(ServerState.InLobby);

                // Call the onSuccess callback if provided
                onSuccess?.Invoke(request);
            }
            // Request failed. Call the onError callback if provided
            else { onError?.Invoke(request); }
        };

        // Remove idle state
        state.Remove(ServerState.Idle);

        // Perform request
        AuthenticatedRequest("match/create", callback: callback, requestJson: new Dictionary<string, object> { { "match_name", matchName } });
    }

    public void JoinMatch(string matchID, Action<TcpRequest> onSuccess = null, Action<TcpRequest> onError = null)
    {
        // Throw exception already busy with an operation
        if (!state.Has(ServerState.Idle)) { throw new OperationInProgress(); }

        // Define callback action
        Action<TcpRequest> callback = delegate (TcpRequest request)
        {
            // Add idle state back in
            state.Add(ServerState.Idle);

            // Check if the request succeeded
            if (request.OK)
            {
                // Add the inLobby state
                state.Add(ServerState.InLobby);

                // Set currentMatchID in class
                currentMatchID = (string)request.responseJson["match_id"];

                // Call the onSuccess callback if provided
                onSuccess?.Invoke(request);
            }
            // Request failed. Call the onError callback if provided
            else { onError?.Invoke(request); }
        };

        // Perform request
        AuthenticatedRequest("match/join", callback: callback, requestJson: new Dictionary<string, object> { { "match_id", matchID } });
    }

    private void Request(string resource, Action<TcpRequest> callback = null, Dictionary<string, object> requestJson = null)
    {
        // Start async request, invoke callback when done
    }

    private void AuthenticatedRequest(string resource, Action<TcpRequest> callback = null, Dictionary<string, object> requestJson = null)
    {
        // Add login auth data into the requestJson dict or throw exception if we aren't logged in
        // Call Request()
    }
}
```

Comment: You might be right. Mod, can you move it?

Comment: Mod doesn't like my flagging for attention to move it. So here it will stay. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2683/move-questions-between-stack-exchange-sites

Comment: This sems like a code-review and thus should also go to codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Indeed, now that you've posted the full (working) code, it makes it a good candidate for codereview.

Comment: Moved to new question: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/197638/server-request-class-async-callbacks

Answer (score 1):

Depending wether the two unique code must always be used by pair or not I would choose a different approach.

If you want to enforce "pair usage", you can use an abstract class:

```
public abstract class MyClass
{
    public void MyFunction(string apples, Action<TcpRequest> onSuccess=null, Action<TcpRequest> onError=null)
    {
        // Throw exception if already busy with an operation
        if (!state.Has(State.Idle)) { throw new OperationInProgress(); }

        // Define callback action
        Action<TcpRequest> callback = delegate (TcpRequest request)
        {
            // Add idle state back in
            state.Add(State.Idle);

            // Check if the request succeeded
            if (request.OK)
            {
                SomethingUnique1();
            }
            // Request failed. Call the onError callback if provided
            else { onError?.Invoke(request); }
        };

        // Remove idle state
        state.Remove(State.Idle);

        SomethingUnique2(callback);
    }
    protected abstract void SomethingUnique1();
    protected abstract void SomethingUnique2(Action<TcpRequest> callback);
}
```

And then implement as many subclasses as needed:

```
public sealed class MyClassVariant1 : MyClass
{
    protected override SomethingUnique1() { /*...*/ }
    protected override SomethingUnique2(Action<TcpRequest> callback) { /*...*/ }
}

public sealed class MyClassVariant2 : MyClass
{
    protected override SomethingUnique1() { /*...*/ }
    protected override SomethingUnique2(Action<TcpRequest> callback) { /*...*/ }
}
```

If you can't enforce pair usage because one "something unique 1" may be used in pair with many "something unique 2" I would foster a decorative approach:

```
public sealed class MyClass
{
    private readonly Action somethingUnique1;
    private readonly Action<TcpRequest> somethingUnique2;
    public MyClass(Action somethingUnique1, Action<TcpRequest> somethingUnique2)
    {
        this.somethingUnique1 = somethinUnique1;
        this.somethinUnique2 = somethingUnique2;
    }
    public void MyFunction(string apples, Action<TcpRequest> onSuccess=null, Action<TcpRequest> onError=null)
    {
        // Throw exception if already busy with an operation
        if (!state.Has(State.Idle)) { throw new OperationInProgress(); }

        // Define callback action
        Action<TcpRequest> callback = delegate (TcpRequest request)
        {
            // Add idle state back in
            state.Add(State.Idle);

            // Check if the request succeeded
            if (request.OK)
            {
                somethingUnique1();
            }
            // Request failed. Call the onError callback if provided
            else { onError?.Invoke(request); }
        };

        // Remove idle state
        state.Remove(State.Idle);

        somethingUnique2(callback);
    }
}
```

And then

```
var variant1 = new MyClass(() => { /* ... */ }, (TcpRequest r) => { /* ... */ }); 
var variant2 = new MyClass(() => { /* ... */ }, (TcpRequest r) => { /* ... */ });
```

Here the approach is more composable and thus, less restrictive.

Comment: I like the first one. I'm trying to implement it now. These functions are members of a class, and the State var is a field of this class. I'm trying to avoid needing to pass in a ref to the parent class in order to set the State var, but I might not have a choice.

Comment: @Oliver so you mean that in `SomethingUnique1` and/or `SomethingUnique2` you have to update the `state` ? You can declare the state as follow to overcome this problem: `protected readonly State state;`. Although the design is a bit bad, it's still better than using `ref`.

Comment: Yea I think I've narrowed this down a path because I've only showed the function. I will put the whole thing in the question.